# Python recursion error, but not using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, msvcrt

I'm not using recursion in my code so I don't get why I'm getting an error about recursion.
...........................................................................................

The code is:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep
import msvcrt 

player_location = [0, 0]
player_dir = [0, 0]
width = int(raw_input('Width:'))
height = int(raw_input('Height:'))

def get_input():
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        return msvcrt.getch()
    else:
        return ''

def update_screen():
    global player_location
    system('cls')
    for i in range(0, (height-1)):
        if i == player_location[0]:
            print (' ' * (player_location[1] - 1)) + 'X' + (' '*(width*2 - player_location[1] - 1)) + '|'
        else:
            print (' ' * width * 2) + '|'
    print ('-' * width * 2) + '+'

 def get_input():
    global player_dir
    player_dir = [0, 0]
    inp = get_input()
    if inp == 'q':
        exit()
    elif inp == 'w':
        player_dir[0] = -1
    elif inp == 's':
        player_dir[0] = 1
    elif inp == 'd':
        player_dir[1] = 1
    elif inp == 'a':
        player_dir[1] = -1

def actions():
    global player_dir, player_location
    player_location[0] += player_dir[0]
    player_location[1] += player_dir[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        update_screen()
        sleep(10)
        get_input()
        actions()
```

The error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Then this line a bunch of times:

```
  File "C:\Python\txtpltfrmr.py", line 29, in get_input
    inp = get_input()
```

And then this line:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: You are using recursion, you just didn't realize it.  Your `get_input` function calls itself.

Comment: "in get_input: inp = get_input()" was supposed to be your hint that maybe the problem was get_input calling get_input.

Comment: Did you look at line 29, in get_input? If only all error messages pinpointed the error so exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def get_input():
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        return msvcrt.getch()
    else:
        return ''

def get_input():
    global player_dir
    player_dir = [0, 0]
    inp = get_input() # INFINITE RECURSION, CALLS ITSELF
```

There is your problem. You have two functions called `get_input` with matching signatures. Rename one of them, probably the first one to something like `get_character`.